# Rails router: Avoiding long helpers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

Consider the following snippet from router.rb

```
resource :user do
   namespace :settings do
      resource :access_filter
   end
   get 'settings'
end
```

This generates the URL's I want (`user/settings/access_filter`), but it produces an undesired directory structure and some long url helpers.

In this case, the helper becomes `new_user_settings_access_filter` and I would prefer just to have `new_access_filter`. And Rails expects the AccessFiltersController to reside in a module named `Settings`.

I would like a way to keep a flat directory structure, a flat url helper structure, but a "nested" URL structure. As long as no parameters are neccessary, I don't think my controllers and views needs to know that access filters are nested under the user model and I would like to retain the opportunity to move them to say `options/access_filter` without breaking the site.

Sugggestions on how to get there would be appreciated.

Comment: one of the most important rails principle is convention over configuration. I think you should add the few extra folders, modules, etc. if your rails app grows, your code will grow also and maybe sometimes you will be glad about the rails conventions :). but this just should be a little hint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only want to prefix the path, you could avoid the nesting and any hassle involved by using a separate `scope`.  Organizationally, this seems to make sense as well, since you effectively want to decouple the access filter routes from user.

```
scope "user/settings" do
  resource :access_filter
end

# then if you wanted to change it later, it's simply
scope "options" do
  resource :access_filter
end
```

[scope](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb#L686) is a lower level function actually used by [namespace](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb#L686).  It's far more flexible, and allows you to decorate paths without changing the controller lookup and route names, among other things.